# Как исправить ошибку RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть часть кода

```
class Creat_Timetable():
    def __init__(self):

        self.all_hours_start = [8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
        self.all_minutes_start = [28,23,28,28,23,28,23]

        Creat_Timetable.CreatWin(self)

    def CreatWin(self): # Создаём главное окно
        global main_win, time

        main_win = Tk ()
        main_win.resizable ( width=False,height=False )
        main_win.geometry ( "700x400")
        main_win.title ( "Timetable" )

        time = Label ( text="" )
        time.place ( x=323,y=0)

        Monday = Label (main_win, text="понедельник" )
        Tuesday = Label (main_win, text="вторник" )
        Wednesday = Label (main_win, text="среда" )
        Thursday = Label (main_win, text="четверг" )
        Friday = Label (main_win, text="пятница" )

        Monday.place ( x=10,y=50 )
        Tuesday.place ( x=190,y=50 )
        Wednesday.place ( x=340,y=50 )
        Thursday.place ( x=450,y=50 )
        Friday.place ( x=580,y=50 )

        Creat_Timetable.CheckTime ( self)
        main_win.mainloop ()
    def CheckTime(self):  # Проверка времяни для сбора информации
        now = datetime.now ()

        if now.minute < 10:
            time_n = str ( now.hour )+":0"+str ( now.minute )
        else:
            time_n = str(now.hour) + ":" + str(now.minute)

        time.configure(text=str(time_n))

        for i in range(0,len(self.all_hours_start)):
            if self.all_minutes_start[i] < 10:
                time_l = str (self.all_hours_start[i] )+":0" + str(self.all_minutes_start[i])
            else:
                time_l = str(self.all_hours_start[i]) + ":" + str(self.all_minutes_start[i])

            if time_n == time_l: # Если время нужное
                print ( app2.schoolParse () )  # Выводим что спарсила программа
                del self.all_hours_start[i], self.all_minutes_start[i] # Удаляем не нужное время
        main_win.after(100000,Creat_Timetable.CheckTime(self))
```

выдаёт ошибку

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/lrd/PycharmProjects/schedule_creation/venv/include/main.py", line 65, in 
>       Creat_Timetable()
>     File "/Users/lrd/PycharmProjects/schedule_creation/venv/include/main.py", line 11, in **init**
>       Creat_Timetable.CreatWin(self)
>     File "/Users/lrd/PycharmProjects/schedule_creation/venv/include/main.py", line 36, in CreatWin
>       Creat_Timetable.CheckTime ( self)
>     File "/Users/lrd/PycharmProjects/schedule_creation/venv/include/main.py", line 62, in CheckTime
>       main_win.after(100000,Creat_Timetable.CheckTime(self))
>     File "/Users/lrd/PycharmProjects/schedule_creation/venv/include/main.py", line 62, in CheckTime
>       main_win.after(100000,Creat_Timetable.CheckTime(self))
>     File "/Users/lrd/PycharmProjects/schedule_creation/venv/include/main.py", line 62, in CheckTime
>       main_win.after(100000,Creat_Timetable.CheckTime(self))
>     [Previous line repeated 988 more times]
>     File "/Users/lrd/PycharmProjects/schedule_creation/venv/include/main.py", line 50, in CheckTime
>       time.configure(text=str(time_n))
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1485, in configure
>       return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1469, in _configure
>       cnf = _cnfmerge((cnf, kw))
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line 100, in _cnfmerge
>       elif isinstance(cnfs, (type(None), str)):
>   RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in **instancecheck**

Comment: Если вы просто хотите увеличить глубину рекурсии, то используйте sys.setrecursionlimit

Comment: Пробовал. Если sys.setrecursionlimit(10000) ничего не меняется. Если sys.setrecursionlimit(100000) выходит Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV) и через пару секунд PyCharm закрывается

Comment: ошибка тут: main_win.after(100000,Creat_Timetable.CheckTime(self))

Comment: Я понимаю, но в чём именно там ошибка?

Comment: Можно сократить до такого: def CheckTime(self): Creat_Timetable.CheckTime(self)

Comment: самовызов функции, тоже пробовал та же ошибка, что и в начале

Comment: Дак в этом и ошибка, что самовызов, такого не должно быть, нет признака окончания рекурсии.

Comment: Попробуйте так: `main_win.after(100000, self.CheckTime)`

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное всё получилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этой строке:

```
main_win.after(100000,Creat_Timetable.CheckTime(self))
```

у вас рекурсивно вызывается метод `CheckTime`, потом его результат передается в метод `after` (точнее, никогда не передается из-за бесконечной рекурсии). В `after` нужно передавать сам метод, без его вызова:

```
main_win.after(100000, self.CheckTime)
```

В целом, конструкции вида `ИмяКласса.метод(self)` лучше везде заменить на `self.метод()` - это одно и то же по сути, но так проще читается. Вызвать метод через класс имеет смысл только для методов класса и статических методов (т.е. для методов с аннотациями `@classmethod` и `@staticmethod`).

Также я бы посоветовал при использовании ООП избавиться от использования глобальных переменных. Вместо глобальных переменных используйте поля объекта.